# Trying to change the environment variable in node.js from the terminal but its value is always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, backend

I'm new to backend development and I have this following JS code using express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

I'm trying to change the environment variable process.env.PORT to a different port from the terminal using `set PORT=5000` (I'm on windows) but whenever it runs, the value inside env.PORT is always undefined, am I doing something wrong? Also, I'm using VS Code.

Comment: How are you running your code? Are you pressing "play" in vscode or doing `node yourfile.js` in the terminal (immediately after you call `set`)?

Comment: You can actually run this ` node index.js -port 5000`. It will get the port assigned in the current env.

Comment: I'm running my code using "node index.js" from the terminal after I'm calling set PORT=5000.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to your code example, you want something like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

// sets port 5000 to default or unless otherwise specified in the environment
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});

// Only works on 3000 regardless of what I set environment port to or how I set
// [value] in app.set('port', [value]).
// app.listen(3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

process.env is a reference to your environment, so you have to set the variable there.

```
SET NODE_ENV=development
```

Comment: This should work and you can go one step further using `dotenv`(https://npmjs.com/dotenv) which will inject anything you have in `.env` file into the code during runtime.

Comment: I'm currently taking a course and I'm just following along with the instructor, in the course the instructor keeps doing what I was trying to do but whenever I try to change any env variable value from the terminal before running the code it doesn't change and just gives undefined whenever I try to log the values.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below script to run my node app for windows.

```
SET NODE_ENV=development& node app.js
```

Comment: Sadly it gives me an error when I try to run this line.

Comment: I used it in my npm script. could you please attach you code how you using.?